# How to create Zoom In Circle transition using ffmpreg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg to concatenate 2 videos (prelude and the actual content). I want the transition to start with a circle that grows from a specific location and opens the view to the second video. I tried using ffmpeg-gl-transition, which seems to have a zoomInCirlce transition, but in that case, the second video looses audio. Are there other ways to achieve this?

Here's a link to a sample,

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this using ffmpeg? I don't doubt that it's possible, but I believe that it would be much easier to do this in a compositing software like After Effects.

Comment: I am looking to automate the process with script rather than have a human do using the composition software. Unless these software have apis